# Receiving errors when multiplying matrices

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, matrix-multiplication

In my Computer Science A AP, we have to do matrix multiplication using two classes.

I keep running into issues using the function to multiply the matrices and getting the product.
This is the first class, declares and initializes the matrices:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r1 = 3, c1 = 4;
        int r2 = 4, c2 = 2;
        int[][] a = {{1, 2, -2, 0}, {-3, 4, 7, 2}, {6, 0, 3, 1}};
        int[][] b = {{-1, 3}, {0, 9}, {1, -11}, {4, -5}};

        // So there are the matrices
        int[][] mult = matrixMult(a, b, r1, c1, c2);
        displayProduct(product);
    }

    public static void displayProduct(int[][] product) {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int[] row : product) {
            for (int column : row) {
                System.out.println(column + "   ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I print out the product if the matrices into one matrix.

And then this is the second class that is supposed to multiply the matrices:

```java
public class MatrixMult {
    public static int[][] matrixMult(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
        int[][] product = new int[r1][c2];
        for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++) {
                    product[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

The errors I receive when I try to run the code are:

```
Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
int[][] mult = matrixMult(a, b, r1, c1, c2);
               ^
symbol:   method matrixMult(int[][],int[][],int,int,int)
location: class Main
Main.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
displayProduct(product);
               ^
symbol:   variable product
location: class Main
MatrixMult.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
int[][] product = new int[r1][c2];
                          ^
symbol:   variable r1
location: class MatrixMult
MatrixMult.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
int[][] product = new int[r1][c2];
                              ^
symbol:   variable c2
location: class MatrixMult
MatrixMult.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++)  {
                    ^
symbol:   variable r1
location: class MatrixMult
MatrixMult.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
  for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++)  {
                      ^
symbol:   variable c2
location: class MatrixMult
MatrixMult.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++)  {
                        ^
symbol:   variable c1
location: class MatrixMult
```

Answer (score 1):

**The variable declarations are in the wrong classes and methods.** The declarations below:

```java
int r1 = 3, c1 = 4;
int r2 = 4, c2 = 2;
int[][] a = {{1, 2, -2, 0}, {-3, 4, 7, 2}, {6, 0, 3, 1}};
int[][] b = {{-1, 3}, {0, 9}, {1, -11}, {4, -5}};
```

These are declared in `Main.main` (Main class, main method), while you tried to call them in `MatrixMult.matrixMult`. Instead, declare them in `matrixMult` (the method) or declare them in MatrixMult (the class) but make them static.

Another problem is that you wrote `matrixMult(a, b, r1, c1, c2);`, passing `a, b, r1, c1, c2` as parameters when matrixMult only takes two parameters: `public static int[][] matrixMult(int[][] a, int[][] b)`.

The stack trace tells you this: it can't find `symbol:   method matrixMult(int[][],int[][],int,int,int`. So just rewrite `public static int[][] matrixMult(int[][] a, int[][] b)` to be `public static int[][] matrixMult(int[][] a, int[][] b, int r1, c1, c2)`.

Remember, the matrixMult does not 'know' what those variables are because they are declared in a different method. It only knows them if they are passed in as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**Code review.** Your code might look something like this:

```java
public class MatrixMult {
    public static int[][] matrixMult(
            // correct number, type and order of variables
            int[][] a, int[][] b, int r1, int c1, int c2)  {
        int[][] product = new int[r1][c2];
        for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++)  {
            for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++)  {
                for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++)  {
                    product[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r1 = 3, c1 = 4;
        int r2 = 4, c2 = 2;

        int[][] a = {{1, 2, -2, 0}, {-3, 4, 7, 2}, {6, 0, 3, 1}};
        int[][] b = {{-1, 3}, {0, 9}, {1, -11}, {4, -5}};

        int[][] mult = matrixMult(a, b, r1, c1, c2);

        displayProduct(mult);
    }

    public static void displayProduct(int[][] product) {
        for (int[] row : product) {
            for (int column : row) {
                // print as a single line without
                // a line separator at the end
                System.out.print(column + "   ");
            }
            // print a line separator
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-3   43   
18   -60   
1   -20
```

---

<sup>See also: [Matrix multiplication using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65999907/14940971)</sup>